# Bean error while printing Hello world with spring boot mvc model

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I'm trying to print hello world with java spring boot MVC adding annotations but it generates this error that indicates that Spring could not find a bean of com.example.HelloWorld.service.BusinessService when attempting to inject it into the HelloWorldApplication class.

Even if I created a bean type withthe annotation @Component

```
Field bs in com.example.HelloWorld.HelloWorldApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.HelloWorld.service.BusinessService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.HelloWorld.service.BusinessService' in your configuration.
```

I added `@component` in the bean class and `@autowired` while declaring the variable but don't understant why I have the bean's error

```
    package com.example.HelloWorld;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private BusinessService bs; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        HelloWorld hw = bs.getHelloWorld();
        System.out.println(hw);
    }
}

package com.example.HelloWorld.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.HelloWorld.model.HelloWorld; 

@Component
public class BusinessService {
    
    public HelloWorld getHelloWorld() {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        return hw;
    }
}


package com.example.HelloWorld.model;

public class HelloWorld {
    private String value = "Hello World !";

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return value;
    }


}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: It would be very usefyll if you wou would post 1) miminal source code needed to reproduce the issue, preferably in a typed formad. Please include all 3 classes, also HelloWorldApplication . 2) Stacktrace from the logs (about 5  lines, if needed someone will ask for more)

Comment: @fascynacja I included all 3 classes

Comment: @fascynacja thank you it fonctionned

Comment: If it works for you you can accept the answer  (the little "check" button) and give it a "up" arrow. In that way other people who have the same problem as you, can quickly find solution  . Good luck with your project, and enjoy stackoverflow:. Here you can fiind simple guide, I recommend to read it:) :https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is create a configuration class:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Configuration
{
    @Bean
    BusinessService businessService() {
        return new BusinessService();
    }
}
```

and in your main class inject this service via constructor:

```
public class HelloWorldApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private BusinessService bs;
    public HelloWorldApplication(BusinessService bs)
    {
        this.bs = bs;
    } ...
}
```